# What is a necessary and sufficient condition for $\lim_{t \to \infty} |x(t)| = \infty $, where $x(t)$ is the solution to an ODE system?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In the course I'm taking for Ordinary Differential Equations, one exercise asks the following question:

Suppose that an ODE system is $x' = A x$ and that $A$ is an $n \times n$  matrix with all eigenvalues real and different. Hence, what conditions on the eigenvalues of $A$ as equivalent to $\lim_{t \to \infty} |x(t)| = \infty $ for all solutions where $x(t)\neq 0$?

Now, this is what I have attempted.

If all the eigenvalues are real and different, I know that I can diagonalize $A$, such that $Q^{-1} A Q = \text{diag}\{\lambda_1,...\lambda_n\}$, and
$$y_i(t) = y_i(0) e^{t\lambda_i}$$

Hence, is the condition that at least one eigenvalue is larger to $1$ equivalent to $\lim_{t\to \infty} |x(t)| = \infty$? If not, what would be the condition?

Comment: Indeed with $\lambda_i>0$ and $y_i(0) \neq 0$ for some $i=1,..,n$ is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

This holds iff all eigenvalues are positive. Note that $A$ must have an eigenbasis.

Suppose $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} |x(t)| = \infty$ for all nontrivial $x$. Then consider some eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. There is a solution such that $x(0) = v$. And the solution to the ODE will be $x(t) = e^{\lambda t} v$. We have $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} |e^{\lambda t} v| = \infty$, so $\lambda > 0$.

On the other hand, suppose all eigenvalues are positive. Let $x(0)$ be written as $\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n v_i u_i$ where $v_i$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ and the $v_i$ are independent. Then we have $x(t) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n v_i u_i e^{\lambda_i t}$. Then take the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ such that $u_j \neq 0$. Then the term $v_j u_j e^{\lambda_j t}$ will dominate for large $t$ and cause the absolute value to go to $\infty$ as $t \to\infty$ since $u_j > 0$.